# How Will Register Transfer work in a Quantum computer ?

Tags: cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, quantum-computing

If i am not wrong a qbit can have any value from 0 to 1 at any given time , But if you are moving some data from a register to another in a quantum computer how will we know what state will be transferred , to the register ?

Comment: It's not exactly a programming question, maybe this should go on some physics SE, but in a nutshell - qbits don't have a single value between 0 and 1, they have a superposition of 0 and 1 values (or rather `|0>` and `|1>`), at varying probabilities. you should read again about qbits (even the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) is a good start)

Comment: @Randomizer , please see the second paragraph of my answer. As you can see, I'm still learning about these things, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [no-cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem) says it's not possible to copy quantum states (pure or mixed). If you want a copy, you have to measure the qubits, collapsing them to classical information, and then copying that - but you loose almost all the information encoded in the system and you're left with normal 0's and 1's.

However, it is possible to transfer a state using [quantum teleportation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wZ35c3oYUE&list=PL1826E60FD05B44E4&index=18) - it destroys the original quantum state and re-creates it in another qubit using a classical information channel and a shared [Bell state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state). But it is not exactly clear how this can be useful in a single processor as you could just use [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming) to the same effect (with a classical computer controlling the quantum processor, you can just tell it to start calling a certain physical qubit by some other name and achieve the same result).